# Rewriting to a different page based on existence of query string?

Tags: php, codex

I have a home page (id = 4) and a form page (id = 5). I want to send them back to the home page if they don't have a query string. But if they *do* have the query string we are looking for, then I want to send them to the form page. This code already works for sending them back to the home page if the slug is just "f1", but I feel/know that I'm missing something. How would I accomplish this?

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  $pmc = '(agnt)(\d{3})';
  add_rewrite_rule('f1', 'index.php?page_id=4', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('f1/' . $pmc . '/?$', 'index.php?page_id=5&pmc=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
function wpd_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'pmc';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution I needed was to add this snippet of code to my custom template file for the form page.

```
$pmc = $_GET['pmc'];
if($pmc == false){
    header('Location: ' . get_bloginfo('url') );
}
```